# Delete a line between two polygons so I have one polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coincident

I have two polygons that are coincident.  I want to merge them in to one polygon and delete the line that is between the two polygons; the merge didn't do it; it kept the line in between them.  How do I get rid of this stupid line in ArcGIS 10.

Comment: if merge didn't work they are not coincident. remember it is a computer. the lines can't just be coincident. they must be exact duplicates.every vertex must be the same.

Comment: Here's a follow up. What if you want to only dissolve the line between 2 parts of a polygon. Specifically, the line between 2 states but not the rest of the US?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113710)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool. Setup the dissolve without specifying a "dissolve field" so that attributes won't be taken into consideration when the dissolve process is performed. If you have to maintain borders between other polygons, specify a dissolve field where the two polygons in question have the same value.